# Error in installing Wine

Tags: wine

I have run:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

but same :(

Here's log:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.34-0ubuntu1~ppa1)
        Recommends: gnome-exe-thumbnailer but it is not going to be installed or
 kde-runtime but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute these commands one by one in Terminal (Crtl+Alt+T) :

```
sudo apt-get install -f

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: Same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enter this in the terminal, and use a older wine first try this:

```
      sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine
      sudo apt-get update 
      sudo apt-get install wine1.4 winetricks
```

and then install a newer one enter this:

```
      sudo apt-get install wine1.7
```

and this might fix the issue on this one.

Comment: Same problem :(

Comment: Can you make a list whit gedit or some other, and it the file called the gpg file in sudoers.